# Upgrading to Swift 2.0 causes an error with NSCODER

Tags: ios, swift

I just updated my xcode 6.4 to 7 and converted my old Swift syntax to the latest one.
Since then, I, obviously, have been having a lot of errors and could not solve the following error.
I screenshotted it. [image]

Does anyone know how to tackle this error issue?

Thank you

Comment: why do you have 2 question marks in the required init?

Comment: Where did that `??` come from? That's not valid Swift 1 either.

Comment: it orginally did not have both of them. When I converted the project, they showed up. And I do not know why it turned out that way. Do you guys have any suggestions btw?

Comment: just delete them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

1. Remove the extra `?` on line 15.
2. Add `public` to your `init` on line 25.

The explanation:

Your `required init` must be public because the class is public. By not specifying visibility, it defaults to internal. Line 25 should read:

```
public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
```

The reason DShaw's solution worked for him but not for you is because his class had internal visibility while yours is public.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the first required Init.

The convert process from swift 1.2/1 to 2 in my projects required me to do so as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in Xcode 7:

```
import UIKit

class TextView: UITextView {

internal var placeholderText: String = "Tap to edit"

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}

required override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    initialize()
}

private func initialize()
{
    // whatever
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. I was trying your solution and I'm still getting an error saying that I should put "public" between required "public" init & required override "public" init. The error msg says " 'required' initializer must be as accessible as its enclosing type."